# Visual studio sql deployment error: The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid

Tags: visual-studio, sqlproj

I am migrating my work from my desktop win 10 to a surface 9 laptop win 11 and I installed vs 2022 (had same on my desktop).
Publishing of my web app has a setting to update the database with my local database schema, this worked find on my desktop but I get an error on the laptop

> Could not generate deployment script.
> Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
> Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)

I have installed the latest DacFac Framework version 16, installed version 15 as well, tried to replace the DLLs in vs 2022 DAC folder but nothing seems to work. has anyone had similar issue?
[Preview Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2CyZ.png)

The deployment script is supposed to be generated here.